# error using already compiled version of openCV

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv

I've used the already compiled version of openCV for Raspberry Pi. [link for anyone who is interested](https://github.com/Nolaan/libopencv_24)

After trying to compile using this command line 
`g++ test3.cpp -o test3 -I/usr/local/include/ -lraspicam -lraspicam_cv -L/opt/vc/lib -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util -I/usr/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lwiringPi -lpthread`

I get the following error lines.

> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::ensureSizeIsEnough(int, int, int, cv::gpu::GpuMat&)'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range const&, cv::ParallelLoopBody const&, double)'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `typeinfo for cv::ParallelLoopBody'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::Mutex::unlock()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::Mutex::lock()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4: undefined reference to cv::TLSDataContainer::getData() const
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4: undefined reference to cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, char const*, unsigned char&, bool, unsigned char (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(unsigned char), std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, char const*, float&, bool, float (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(float), std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, char const*, short&, bool, int (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(int), std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::Mutex::Mutex()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::TLSDataContainer::TLSDataContainer()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::ParallelLoopBody::~ParallelLoopBody()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::Mutex::~Mutex()'
>
> //usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4: undefined reference to `cv::TLSDataContainer::~TLSDataContainer()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not linked the executable against several libraries that are required by the program

Try using this:

```
g++ -lpthread `pkg-config opencv --libs` -I/usr/local/include/ -lraspicam -lraspicam_cv -L/opt/vc/lib -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util -I/usr/include -lwiringPi test3.cpp -o test3
```

Comment: thanks alot. It works, but It worked in the past with my command too.